# Is there a way to add rel='preload' using addScript/addStyleSheet?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

I want to display some of the styles and scripts using `rel='preload'` to make my pages load faster - referring to the [Google Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/preload).

```
<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="main.js" as="script">
```

Is there any way to do this using addScript/addStyleSheet in Joomla?

```
$document->addStyleSheet("css/style.css");
$document->addScript("js/us.script.js");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer this myself too as I've been looking into lazy loading assets recently.

`preload` may seem like it asynchronously loads files but it doesn't. They're still considered render blocking.

This also applies if you also just add your assets to below the closing `</body>` tag as there's still remaining HTML to be rendered.

You're best approach will be to add a small snippet of Javascript of code before the closing `</body>` tag of your template:

```
<script>
// Lazy load all your CSS and fonts
for (const css of [
  '<?php echo $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/template.css'; ?>',
  // You can define more CSS or font files here in the array
]) {
  const link = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('link'));
  script.rel = 'stylesheet';
  script.href = css;
}

// Lazy load all your JS
for (const js of [
  '<?php echo $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/template.js'; ?>',
  // You can define more Javascript files here in the array
]) {
  const script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
  script.async = false;
  script.src = js;
}
</script>
```

Note that I've written this in ES6. You can transpile back to ES5 if you wish to support IE11.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the usage of `preload` correctly, in 3.x you can add these links manually with `addHeadlink()`:

```
// Preload resources
$mediaVersion = $this->mediaVersion ? '?' . $this->mediaVersion : '';
$this->addHeadLink($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/template.css' . $mediaVersion, 'preload', 'rel', array('as' => 'style'));
$this->addHeadLink($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/template.js' . $mediaVersion, 'preload', 'rel', array('as' => 'script'));

// Load resources
JHtml::_('script', 'template.js', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));
JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'template.css', array('version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true));
```

Note, document's `$mediaVersion` property works when added resources have `auto` value for `version`. If you're using a different method for generating version, change it on `preload` links accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Joomla 4.0 will have this possibility:

> https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/15880

Comment: This post is low-value in terms of what will stand the test of time on Joomla Stack Exchange. It is important that when you post "an answer" that it is not merely a "link-only answer".  Links are fragile -- if they get moved or removed from the destination site, you answer will be rendered entirely useless.  The truth is, your post is only mentioning that this issue is a possibility in Joomla 4.0 and is not actually a "solution".  I will advise you to remove this post and instead write it as a comment under your question or add it to your question body. I have flagged as "not an answer".

Comment: That said, once this solution is a legitimate solution in J4.0, then you are welcome to edit this post into a complete and educational solution and then undelete it so that it is available for future researchers.